# Facebook like gate not receiving whether user has liked the page or not when live

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Hope someone out there knows the answer to this, the tab app was working fine when in testing but when live facebook is not including whether the user has liked the page or not in the signed request?!

It was working fine when in development mode :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like gating is not possible and not allowed anymore, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> The 'liked' property will no longer be returned in the 'signed_request' object for Page Tab apps created after today. From November 5, 2014 onwards, the 'liked' property will always return 'true' regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.

They also change the platform policy:

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a Page. This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page. It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app's Page. To ensure quality connections and help businesses reach the people who matter to them, we want people to like Pages because they want to connect and hear from the business, not because of artificial incentives. We believe this update will benefit people and advertisers alike.

Comment: Thanks for this @Luschn, sorry it took so long to come back to you. The reason it was working fine within development is because I had created my test app a long time ago.